# Lexicographically comparing two strings

Tags: java, string, compare, lexicographic

I am trying to find out lexicographically smallest and largest substring of length z which is taken from input.
I don't know why but the if condition is not working where I am trying to find the minimum substring.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);

        String s=ip.next();
        int z=ip.nextInt();
        String max="";
        String mini="";
        String x="";

        for(int i=0;i<s.length()-z;i++) {
                x=s.substring(i,i+z);
                if(x.compareTo((mini))<0) //this is not working
                    mini=x;

                if(x.compareTo((max))>0)
                    max=x;
            }
        System.out.print(mini);
        System.out.print(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: see the code where i am trying to find minimum substring,it is not working

Comment: you have initially declared mini as empty string so it is not changing. You should initialize both mini and max as any z-length substring of the input string. `mini = max = s.substring(0, z);`

Comment: @RahulJain thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in declaring of both variables `mini` and `max`

you already initialize them as empty string so the condition will not return the expected result when comparing them to `x` and their values won't change

you can initialize them:

```
 mini = s.substring(0, z);
 max  = s.substring(0, z);
```

**Edit**:

if you try to test this condition :

`x.compareTo((""))` it will always return value bigger than `0` so `mini` won't change at any case.